# Creating a PHP iframe form to post data to email address as well as database table

Tags: php, mysql, iframe

The first thing I'm struggling to figure out is if it's possible to add this PHP form to an iframe so I can drop it on several different sites (Facebook, Wordpress, personal sites etc). 
If not how else can I create a form that will allow me to drop the iframe code on different sites and still function correctly?

Currently my form just submits the data to my email but I want the data to also get posted and stored within a database. Can I do this within an iframe?

Below is my form..

HTML

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
<p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
<p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
<p>Phone</p> <input type="text" name="phone">

<p>Request Phone Call:</p>
Yes:<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" name="call"><br />
No:<input type="checkbox" value="No" name="call"><br />

<p>Website</p> <input type="text" name="website">

<p>Priority</p>
<select name="priority" size="1">
<option value="Low">Low</option>
<option value="Normal">Normal</option>
<option value="High">High</option>
<option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
</select>
<br />

<p>Type</p>
<select name="type" size="1">
<option value="update">Website Update</option>
<option value="change">Information Change</option>
<option value="addition">Information Addition</option>
<option value="new">New Products</option>
</select>
<br />

<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$call = $_POST['call'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Website: $website \n Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "youremail@here.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

If you host the iframe on your host, you have direct access to your database. The mail.php file should do the posting.

Use this inside your code, before or after mailing the message:

```
define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
define('DBNAME', '');
define('DBUSER', '');
define('DBPASS', '');

function nuukDb() {
    $nuukDb = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DBHOST . ';dbname=' . DBNAME . ';charset=utf8', DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $nuukDb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $nuukDb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$nuuk = $nuukDb->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename (value1, value2, value3) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone')");
$nuuk->execute();
```

Reference: https://github.com/wolffe/nuuk

Comment: Thank you @ciprian !! Is it a negative to have direct access to my database? When you say mail.php should I have separate pages for the mailing part and the posting to the table part? Will putting this form into an iframe affect the sending of the data and the mail?

Comment: You should have only one page for both mailing and the database interaction. There is no direct access to your database, as the PHP code is interpreted, thus invisible to anyone. Putting the code inside an iframe won't affect the sending of data and email. Another way of doing this would be to use AJAX to call a script on your server. But this is another question.

Comment: Ok, I'll stick to this solution for now. Thanks for your help @Ciprian